# Asynchronous WCF service call

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous

I'm calling WCF service asynchronously from the WP page using EAP:

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client proxy = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
proxy.loginCompleted += DoLogin;
proxy.loginAsync("user", "password");
```

And in the Rererence.cs I see the following code that looks like APM:

```
public System.IAsyncResult Beginlogin(string usn, string pwd, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState) 
{
    object[] _args = new object[2];
    _args[0] = usn;
    _args[1] = pwd;
    System.IAsyncResult _result = base.BeginInvoke("login", _args, callback, asyncState);
    return _result;
}

public bool Endlogin(System.IAsyncResult result)
{
    object[] _args = new object[0];
    bool _result = ((bool)(base.EndInvoke("login", _args, result)));
    return _result;
}
```

Why do I have APM methods when I'm calling WCF service using EAP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you generate a *Service Reference* and set it to *generate asynchronous operations* on the client side, from .NET 3.5 and above, it will call `svcutil.exe` with the `/async /tcv:Version35` parameters and will generate both APM and EAP asynchronous operations.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When using /tcv:Version35 with the /async switch, both **event-based and
>   callback/delegate-based** asynchronous methods are generated. In
>   addition, support for LINQ-enabled DataSets and DateTimeOffset is
>   enabled.